# EF Code-First - Fluent API Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have a set of relationships that I am not sure to to set up in FluentAPI.  Here is my distilled model:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Reference> References { get; set; }
}
public class Reference
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Relationship { get; set; } // Brother, Father, etc
  public virtual Customer LinkedCustomer { get; set; }
  public virtual Customer ReferenceFor { get; set; }
}
```

ReferenceFor links back to References in Customer.  LinkedCustomer references the Customer that the Reference is based on.  Basically, a Customer can be a reference for any other number of customers.

I think that this is a Many-Many and a Many-One set of relationships, but I am not sure how to specify them in Fluent API.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasMany(x => x.References)

modelBuilder.Entity<References>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasOptional(x => x.LinkedCustomer)
            .WithMany(x => x.Customer)

modelBuilder.Entity<References>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasOptional(x => x.ReferenceFor)
            .WithMany(x => x.Customer)
```